# FFmpeg metadata tags for YouTube 3D side-by-side movies

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

YouTube requires specific metadata tags for 3D Side-By-Side format movies.  If the tag is not there then YouTube does not give the anaglyph playback options for the end user.

Their "help" is here
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7278886?hl=en-GB

I am trying to get FFmpeg to add the MP4 tag when building my movie.

Code that works now for a series of PNG files into a MP4.

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -framerate 60 -i "VID%05d.PNG" -c:v libx264 -preset:v veryslow -profile:v high -crf 15 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -an -y "OUTPUT.MP4"
```

But when I add the tag from the YouTube help page

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -framerate 60 -i "VID%05d.PNG" -c:v libx264 -preset:v veryslow -profile:v high -crf 15 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -an -y -x264opts "frame-packing=3:frame-packing-interpret=1:frame-packing-quincunx=0:frame-packing-grid=0,0,0,0" "OUTPUT.MP4"
```

I get this error from FFmpeg

```
[libx264 @ 0000000002a8c3a0] bad option 'frame-packing-interpret': '1'
```

This page (ignore the proselytising)

http://www.pantherdynamics.yolasite.com/panther-dynamics-blog/uploading-3dsbs-content-to-youtube

says you only need to use this tag

```
-x264opts frame-packing=3
```

Using that does make FFmpeg finish correctly, but the SBS is still ignored by YouTube

The YouTube engineer blog post here

https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/09/getting-3d-content-on-youtube_8.html

links to an older supposed 3D movie that also does not give 3D options any more.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubRHSg5daMs

So maybe even YouTube's own 3D movies are crippled?

What am I doing wrong?  Any FFmpeg gurus able to help?

Comment: Weird. Other than the first option, all the other x264opts keys never existed in x264. Mux to Matroska instead adding `-metadata:s:v:0 stereo_mode=1`

Comment: OK, can you tell me what syntax I need for MKV encoding?  I will give it a go and see if YouTube shows the 3D option.  Since posting I see 99.999% of all previous 3D movies now show the side by side images with no 3D options.  Looks like YouTube canned 3D support since ditching their flash player and going with the new HTML5 player.  I cannot find any official answer though.

Comment: Same command but output extn is mkv and add the metadata tag.

Comment: MKV side by side with the -metadata:s:v:0 stereo_mode=1 works.  But YouTube only allows an option for red/blue anaglyph.  They have crippled the 3D options.  And all previous 3D SBS movies are now disabled 3D.  What a mess.

Comment: This issue has been going since at least May 2016 and YouTube is not going to anything about it.  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/tQLP5Nf2hFg;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/sbs  All those previous 3D SBS format movies need to be manually downloaded and played through a 3rd party app now to work.  At least I know it isn't an issue with FFmpeg now.

Answer (score 1):

`stereo_mode=1` is wrong for MKV. use `left_right` instead.

I know that's still on the YouTube advice page, but it's wrong (I uploaded both to YouTube yesterday and only left_right works).  That's why some people think YouTube have dropped support for MKV 3D, it still works as of today.